# CSRF token missing in the first post request Flask

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying out flask, I have a form served from the following route:

```
@app.route("/register",methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        employee = Employee(name=form.name,emp_id=form.emp_id,email=form.email,password=form.password)
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('register.html',form=form)
```

I wanted to have client side validation just to check whether the entered email exists in the database. I tried submitting the email field to a different route which is given below to see how things work.

```
@app.route('/email',methods=['POST'])
def email():
    print(request.form['email'])
    return "success"
```

The following is my javascript code for ajax request which gets called when a blur event happens in the input field.

```
function emailSubmit(event) {

    console.log($('#email').serialize());
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $('#email').serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data) // display the returned data in the console.
        }
    });

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrfToken)
            }
        }
    })

}
```

The javascript file is in the static folder and the url and csrf_token is supplied using global variables.

The issue is that on first post request to the route "email" I am getting a

> *Bad Request "The CSRF token is missing."*

But everything works perfectly fine from the next post request onwards. The same csrf token is sent in the next request too. Why is this happening?
I have enabled csrf protection globally.